# Unsuccessful queries for in uploaded Word documents using example core and schema

Tags: solr

**Short Version:**  What do I need to do to successfully query for terms in Word documents that have been uploaded using the example core?  (**EDIT**:  The question originally was "What do I need to do to search for terms that are adjacent to tabs and newlines (i.e. \t, \n) in an uploaded Word document?"  But the problem had nothing at all to do with tabs or newlines.

**Long Version:**

I am using Solr 4.6.1.  I am running an unmodified version of the example core that is started by running `java -jar start.jar` in the `example` directory.  The `schema.xml` in use is `example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml` and is unmodified (it is the one downloaded with the distribution), so I won't post it unless someone says it is helpful.

After uploading a Word document to Solr with the command `http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=yabba&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true` there are hundreds of tab and newline characters (i.e. `\n` and `\t`) in the `attr_content` field.  When a string occurs only once in the document, and is adjacent to one of these characters, queries for that term are not successful.

A specific example is an uploaded Word document that after upload contains "Vorname:\t\t\tYasmin" in the `attr_content` field.  The original document contained "Vorname:", then two tab characters, then "Yasmin" (the string "\t" does not appear in the document).  The string "Yasmin" appears only in that location in the document.

When I query for "Yasmin" with the query `http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=Yasmin&wt=json&indent=true` I get no results.  Queries for terms that are **not** next to a `\t` or a `\n` are successful.

What can I do so that a query for a term next to a tab or newline will be successful?  Must I change the way the document is uploaded?  Or change the way the search is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version**

You are indexing the content in a field that is not searched and not copied to the default search field named `text`.

**Long Version**

First you are mapping the actual content of the file to a dynamic field. In the schema.xml of the example you will find the line

```xml
<dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

This is where your content goes, initally. When being filled that field will be called `attr_content`, as you name it that way when posting the content of the file with `fmap.content=attr_content`. But against which fields are your queries being directed?

Therefore you need to have a look into the `solrconfig.xml of collection1`. There you can see in the middle:

```xml
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Ok, so the default field (df) is `text`. This is not where you content goes, when being indexed. But probably this is covered by a `<copyfield>` in the schema.xml? Let's have a look:

```xml
<copyField source="cat" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="manu" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="features" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="includes" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="manu" dest="manu_exact"/>

<copyField source="price" dest="price_c"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="author" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="keywords" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="content_type" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="resourcename" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="url" dest="text"/>

<copyField source="author" dest="author_s"/>
```

Nope. `attr_content` is not copied to `text`. This is why your query fails. The content is just not indexed in the field text.

**What to do against it?**

1. Query with the field the content is index in `q=attr_content:yasmin` or in copy'n'paste style `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=attr_content%3Ayasmin&wt=json&indent=true`. This delivery the one document locally I index with the content you posted.
2. Add a copy directive in the schema.xml. Below the whole block of `copyFields` you find in you schema.xml you could add `<copyField source="attr_content" dest="text" />` which would add only the content field to text or `<copyField source="attr_*" dest="text" />` which would add all other dynamic `attr_*` fields also.
3. Change the way you post the file for being index. You can change the parameter `fmap.content=attr_content` to `fmap.content=content`. The content of the file would then be stored in the field `content`, which already has a copy directive to the field `text`. So instead of `http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=yabba&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true` do it with `http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=yabba&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=content&commit=true`

Comment: I won't have time for a couple weeks to work on this, and I can't really mark the answer as correct until I test it.  But it certainly looks to be correct.  I believe the bounty will go to you even if it's not marked correct as yours is the highest upvoted (and only) answer.

Comment: Nope, an answer requires 2 upvotes for the automatic system. Have a read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work but well, so be it :)

Comment: I didn't know that, and your hard work deserves the 50 points even if I can't review it yet.

Comment: Your answer works (you knew that already didn't you?).  Now, of your three solutions which might you recommend if I'm going to create an index of a couple hundred thousand documents that I will make available for searching to my colleagues through the API (I won't provide my own interface).  Option 3 seems to me to be the best because users don't have to know which field to query (as in option 1) and it doesn't cause double storage of the contents (which I think option 2 would do).  What is your opinion?

Comment: I would also go for option 3. It feels natural the way the whole schema is designed.